# Change menu order on backend of wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, backend

I'm in the backend of wordpress, I have a custom post type called 'work' and I want to re-order the work projects (in the backend) by menu order. I've found an action hook called 'pre_get_posts' which returns the query, but the query has the post_type listed as 'page'. How do I hook into the query that prints the custom post types in the back end?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish but don't know the right hook or filter:

```
function search_filter($query) {

    if($_GET['post_type'] == 'work' && is_admin())
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'menu_order';

    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'search_filter');
```

Comment: I found a plugin that does what I want and more. It's called Simple Page Ordering. Also includes drag and drop to re-order.

Comment: Awe.. Its a great plugin.. :)